# Button not leading me to 2nd page

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I wrote some code and it won't lead me to the 2nd page that I listed. How do I fix this so it brings me to my second page? The name and everything listed is correct.

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="" href="2.html" class="btn btn1">Page 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button>`s don't have an href... `<a>` tags do and they are intended for navigation

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, I put the button tag inside of the a tag like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="2.html"><button class="btn btn1">Page 2</button></a>
</div>
```

This meant I kept the design I had and the button works completely fine

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do something like this would be through a `<form>` tag. Here is an example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="2.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Page 2">
  </form>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could try an `<a>` tag like this:

```html
<a href="2.html"><button>Page 2</button></a>
```

Comment: I just get the error
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: bramble_0.1.26/2.html
RequestId: 723C5C4B582E9EA8
HostId: kBqVmy0Xyzu1g0VVHw6t0Q+0jJSMNkJYyJPJ8g2zm+KmVggnGpasEU07edON+0Ozag51SG8leRQ=

Comment: @KingRealzYT Try adding a ```method="POST"``` tag. So the form tag looks like this: ```<form action="2.html" method="POST">```

Comment: Why isn't using an `<a>` the best way? It's what it is designed for

Comment: it gives me more errors, do you know how to do it with the way i have it? (the reason is the text is a certain way so when u hover over it, gets filled up)

Comment: @KingRealzYT Hm, maybe you could try the alternative method for it. It looks something like this: ```<a href="2.html"><button>Page 2</button></a>```